# Errors in automatic backup

Tags: orientdb

I keep getting errors similar to below during automatic backup. Offline backup works fine. Check database shows no errors. Any idea what I can do to fix this? I'm using version 2.2.33

```
2018-03-10 03:29:32:308 INFO  {db=db} ok size=1024b compressedSize=15 ratio=99% elapsed=0msException `2A65CB6D` in storage `plocal:/home/dmsadmin/dms2/env/duri_prod/db`: 2.2.33 (build 77584cd6827f647cf4aa231cf27bd6f10bc04e2c, branch 2.2.x)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Directory /home/dmsadmin/dms2/env/duri_prod/db/db.1045.wal not found
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.compression.impl.OZIPCompressionUtil.addFolder(OZIPCompressionUtil.java:145)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.compression.impl.OZIPCompressionUtil.addFolder(OZIPCompressionUtil.java:127)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.compression.impl.OZIPCompressionUtil.compressDirectory(OZIPCompressionUtil.java:57)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.paginated.OLocalPaginatedStorage.backup(OLocalPaginatedStorage.java:229)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.document.ODatabaseDocumentTx.backup(ODatabaseDocumentTx.java:3061)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.handler.OAutomaticBackup.fullBackupDatabase(OAutomaticBackup.java:353)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.handler.OAutomaticBackup$1.run(OAutomaticBackup.java:183)
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
$ANSI{green {db=db}} Error on backup of database 'plocal:/home/dmsadmin/dms2/env/duri_prod/db' to directory: /backup/dms2/
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Directory /home/dmsadmin/dms2/env/duri_prod/db/db.1045.wal not found
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.compression.impl.OZIPCompressionUtil.addFolder(OZIPCompressionUtil.java:145)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.compression.impl.OZIPCompressionUtil.addFolder(OZIPCompressionUtil.java:127)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.compression.impl.OZIPCompressionUtil.compressDirectory(OZIPCompressionUtil.java:57)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.paginated.OLocalPaginatedStorage.backup(OLocalPaginatedStorage.java:229)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.document.ODatabaseDocumentTx.backup(ODatabaseDocumentTx.java:3061)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.handler.OAutomaticBackup.fullBackupDatabase(OAutomaticBackup.java:353)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.handler.OAutomaticBackup$1.run(OAutomaticBackup.java:183)
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)

 2018-03-10 03:29:32:313 INFO  Automatic Backup finished: 0 ok, 1 errors
```

Comment: Hi, it seems that the directory /home/dmsadmin/dms2/env/duri_prod/db/db.1045.wal cannot be found maybe because doesn't exists. Hope it helps, Regards

Comment: Yah, I see that, but why is orientdb backup looking for a file that doesn't exist? It has this same error every time. I assume it can be run when the database is running? Anyone at orientdb??